# Fedora Email Forwarding (Postfix)

Tags: email, postfix, fedora

I would like to forward all email sent to non-existant users on my fedora server to my gmail account.  Is there a simple way to do this?

How would I forward all email?

Answer (score 1):

Set "mydestination=" in main.cf to include the domains that you receive mail for.
You will need to make sure that each of those resolves correctly in DNS, I believe.

Then add or edit "virtual_alias_maps" in main.cf to look like this:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Then add the domains to /etc/postfix/virtual:

```
@example.org     you@gmail.com
@someotherdomain.com   you@gmail.com
```

run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`

and restart postfix if you edited main.cf at all.

This will forward mail sent to example.org and someotherdomain.com to your gmail account.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to read Postfix docs? [Postfix Virtual Domain Hosting Howto](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) is your best friend, [Mail forwarding domains](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#forwarding) chapter, if I'll show topic-for-you

```
 1 /etc/postfix/main.cf:
 2     virtual_alias_domains = example.com ...other hosted domains...
 3     virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
 4 
 5 /etc/postfix/virtual:
 6     postmaster@example.com postmaster
 7     joe@example.com        joe@somewhere
 8     jane@example.com       jane@somewhere-else
 9     # Uncomment entry below to implement a catch-all address
10     # @example.com         jim@yet-another-site
```

> Line 10: The commented out entry (text after #) shows how one would
>   implement a catch-all virtual alias that receives mail for **every
>   example.com address not listed** in the virtual alias file

RTFM, "postmaster"

Comment: I wanted to forward mail from _any_ domain.

Comment: @Richard-RogueWaveLimited - add one wildcarded alias for every domain in virtual_alias_domains