# How to forward "unknown user" email to another server (Postfix)

Tags: email, postfix, forwarding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fedora Email Forwarding (Postfix)](https://serverfault.com/questions/313435/fedora-email-forwarding-postfix)

I would like to forward any emails received for any unknown user to an email address on another server.  I'm using Postfix.

How do I configure Postfix to do this?

Comment: You might want to look at the answer to the other question you asked about this: http://serverfault.com/questions/313435/fedora-email-forwarding-postfix